# Load instruction in LLVM doesn't load the expected value

Tags: assembly, clang, llvm, x86-64, llvm-ir

I have the following LLVM IR code where I try to perform some assembly instructions where I use registers that I created myself.

```
;[ASM] mov dword ptr [RBP-0x4], 0xa
;[Def] [(i64 %RBP + i64 0xfffffffffffffffc)] := i32 0xa
%T_0_14 = add i64 %RBP , -4
%T_0_17 = zext i32 10 to i64
%T_0_18 = inttoptr i64 %T_0_14 to i64* 
store i64 %T_0_17 , i64* %T_0_18
;------------------------------------
;[ASM] mov EDX, dword ptr [RBP-0x4]
;[Def] i64 %RDX := zext:I64([(i64 %RBP + i64 0xfffffffffffffffc)]:I32)
%T_0_28 = add i64 %RBP , -4
%T_0_29 = inttoptr i64 %T_0_28 to i64* 
%T_0_27 = load i64 , i64* %T_0_29
store i64 %T_0_27 , i64* @RDX
%ans = load i64, i64* @RDX 
ret i64 %ans
```

From the above code I expect `@RDX` to contain the value `0xa` or `10`, however when I run this code it outputs `0`. In the first part of the code I convert `%RBP-4` to pointer which is `%T_0_18` and store `0x10` there. In the second part I load the value from that address to `@RDX`, however this time it is done using the local variable `%T_0_27` which should be same as `%T_0_18`.
What would be the problem?

**Edit 1:**  the registers are defined as shown below:

```
%struct.State = type { %struct.FLAGS, %struct.GPR } 
%struct.FLAGS = type { i64, %struct.Flag, i64, %struct.Flag, i64, 
%struct.Flag, i64, %struct.Flag, i64, %struct.Flag, i64, %struct.Flag } 
%struct.Reg = type { i64 } 
%struct.Flag = type { i1 } 
%struct.GPR = type { i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg, i64, %struct.Reg } 
@reg_state =  global %struct.State zeroinitializer %union.anon = type { i64 } 
@shadow_stack = internal global [1048576 x i64] zeroinitializer 
@RAX = private alias i64, getelementptr inbounds (%struct.State, %struct.State* @reg_state, i32 0, i32 1, i32 1, i32 0) 
@RBX = private alias i64, getelementptr inbounds (%struct.State, %struct.State* @reg_state, i32 0, i32 1, i32 3, i32 0) 
@RCX = private alias i64, getelementptr inbounds (%struct.State, %struct.State* @reg_state, i32 0, i32 1, i32 5, i32 0) 
@RDX = private alias i64, getelementptr inbounds (%struct.State, %struct.State* @reg_state, i32 0, i32 1, i32 7, i32 0)
...
```

Edit 2: I have also defined register variables locally:

```
define i64 @func_1020() {

bb_4128:        ; <label>:4128:
call void @initStack() 
%RAX = load i64, i64* @RAX 
%RBX = load i64, i64* @RBX 
%RCX = load i64, i64* @RCX 
%RDX = load i64, i64* @RDX 
%RSI = load i64, i64* @RSI 
%RDI = load i64, i64* @RDI 
%RSP = load i64, i64* @RSP 
%RBP = load i64, i64* @RBP 
%R8 = load i64, i64* @R8 
%R9 = load i64, i64* @R9 
...
```

Comment: Some values you're using have `%` prefix, which means they are local. The `%RBX` and `@RBX` are different things. Are you sure your code is correct?

Comment: @arrowd I edited the post. I have declared the registers locally too.

Comment: Try stepping over your code with `lli` under a debugger. And don't post screenshots of the code.

Comment: @arrowd Thank you for your feedback. Can you give me any resources about how to debug using lli? I tried to look up for debuggers for llvm before, but kinda got lost.

Comment: @arrowd can I debug my code without generating binary from my .ll file?

Comment: Yes, with `lli`. Build it with debugging symbols and use debugger to step over instructions of your IR file.

Comment: @arrowd Can you give me any resources about how to debug using lli?